# Java 8 streams nonNull on properties of objects

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have the following snippet that collects specific objects which have a `name` string property that contains a specific filter `filterName`.

```
List<Foo> filteredFoo= fooList.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(myFoo -> {
                            if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(myFoo.getName()))
                                return false;
                            return myFoo.getName().contains(filterName);
                        }
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It works as expected but I was wondering whether is there a more elegant way to write the `if-statement` in a functional way and check for empty or null properties in a nicer fashion than having the conditional block in the filter.

Comment: I'm confused. You have decided that `Objects::nonNull` needs to be a separate filter but everything else needs to be in a single one. Why's that?

Comment: @zeroflagL it is done that way for readability purposes, the Objects:nonNull works at object level where the second filter acts on properties of the object itself. I don't know if this has any impact from a performance perspective, but for readability I think it's useful.

Comment: That's my point: If you strive for readability, then why do you have a complex second filter instead of separate and maybe reusable ones, like  `Foo::hasName` e.g.?

Comment: I am quite new to java8 and my hunch is that custom filters would have required some implementation in my model right? In this scenario this is the only place where filtering would have been used, therefore my questions is: would it make sense to have custom filters if used only once? If yes, I would like to have an example on how would it be implemented. Someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace second `filter` with following:

```
.filter(myFoo -> Optional.ofNullable(myFoo.getName())
                         .filter(n -> n.contains(filterName))
                         .isPresent())
```

or even:

```
.filter(myFoo -> {
    String name = myFoo.getName();
    return name != null && name.contains(filterName)
 })
```

Comment: In your first example `!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(n)` is pointless.

Comment: @zero could you explain? `name` may be `null` or empty. Optional resolve only first case imo.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's empty or not. An empty String doesn't contain `filterName` and you check that anyway. Also `!n.isEmpty()` would be more concise.

Comment: Still, `!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(name) && name.contains(filterName)` is unnecessarily verbose. Unless you want to add a 3rd party library requirement to your project at all costs, you can simply say `name!=null && name.contains(filterName)`. As @zeroflagL already pointed out, the implied `isEmpty()` check is obsolete and you don’t need a utility method for a plain `…!=null` check.

Answer (score 2):

Go for the functional style, for the result expression:

```
.filter(foo -> foo.getName() != null && foo.getName().contains(filterName))
```

Splitting would not bring more simplicity:

```
.filter(foo -> foo.getName() != null)
.filter(foo -> foo.getName().contains(filterName))
```

Using predicates on Foo::getName (Objects::isNull) is senseless complicated too, just in order to spare a variable.

If filterName is not empty itself, Strings.isEmptyOrNull is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Foo Class then move the if conditions to a method `isSameName` and use filter as below

```
filter(myFoo -> {return myFoo.isSameName(filterName);})
```